# Messenger persistent menu not visible

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, bots

I'm currently developing a Facebook messenger bot. However, I can't attach a persistent menu to it.

I read the requirements [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/messenger-profile/persistent-menu):

> ```
> The user must be on Messenger v106 or above on iOS or Android.
> The page the bot is attached to must be published.
> The bot must be set to "public" in the developer console.
> The bot must have passed the approval process for pages_messaging permission
> ```

And all those are met.

When I set the menu, I receive this feedback from Facebook:

```
Array
(
    [result] => success
)
```

However, it's still not displayed neither on my Android device, nor in the web Facebook. I deleted the conversation and re-entered several times, with no success.

By the way, I'm using [this lib](https://github.com/pimax/fb-messenger-php) for Graph api, just in case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, the point is that you have to send an array of menus for every locale, but strangely Facebook doesn't warn in case your request is wrong

Comment: What do you mean by locale. How did you formatted the locale?

Answer (score 0):

Xameeramir, I meant something like this. Notice how the menus are different for each locale.

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
"persistent_menu":[
    {
      "locale":"default",
      "composer_input_disabled":true,
      "call_to_actions":[
        {
          "title":"My Account",
          "type":"nested",
          "call_to_actions":[
            {
              "title":"Pay Bill",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"PAYBILL_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"History",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"HISTORY_PAYLOAD"
            },
            {
              "title":"Contact Info",
              "type":"postback",
              "payload":"CONTACT_INFO_PAYLOAD"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "type":"web_url",
          "title":"Latest News",
          "url":"http://petershats.parseapp.com/hat-news",
          "webview_height_ratio":"full"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "locale":"zh_CN",
      "composer_input_disabled":false
    }
  ]
}' "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messenger_profile?access_token=YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN_HERE"
```